# Are answers supposed to be sorted by time of writing?

Tags: support

I've noticed today that answers no longer seem to be ordered by the number of votes they have received, and instead are sorted in time order (most recent first).

Was this an intentional design change or is it a bug? If it was a design change, is there a way to still view answers by number of votes? Where do design changes like this get discussed?

I've tagged this with "bug", but since it could instead be "status-by-design", please delete as appropriate.

**Update**
<strike>I'm more convinced it's not kosher by the fact that Stack Overflow has retained the top voted first sort order.</strike> Turns out it was just me being stupid.

Comment: can you give some examples?

Comment: It was happening on all the questions I viewed, but I think @Reg hit it on the head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the [votes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/what-words-are-commonly-mispronounced-by-literate-people-who-read-them-before-the?answertab=votes#tab-top) tab above the answers:

[image: Votes]

Your preference will be stored in a cookie, so you won't have to do that again on the next question you view.

Comment: That's the ticket. I have never noticed the sorting options before, so I must have hit one by accident! Thanks Reg.